# Why is vim swapping case on forward-delete?

Tags: macos, terminal, vim, terminal.app

## Vim + Catalina

I just switched to MacOS Catalina which has zsh and vim 8.1 out-of-the-box.

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Dec 13 2019 14:45:40)
Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-1312
Compiled by root@apple.com
```

I use Karabiner Elements and BetterTouchTool to map Caps Lock to `delete_or_backspace` and Delete to `delete_forward` (aka `fn`+`delete`).

## Delete Forward => Case Swap

I'm having an issue where the use of `delete_forward` (`fn`+`delete`) replaces whatever is under the cursor with the opposite case.

For example, suppose I have this text:

```
func SomeFunc() {
  return true
}
```

Whether I stay in command(?) mode or I'm in insert mode, using forward delete will swap the case, like this:

```
FUNC sOMEfUNC() {
  RETURN TRUE
}
```

## What my `delete_forward` looks like:

It seems to be functioning as expected in all other programs. This is the escape sequence that I get for it:

```bsh
cat 
hello^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~^[[3~
```

That's me typing 5 letters ('hello') and then hitting forward delete 5 times.

Also, here's what I get from `:set t_kD` inside of vim:

```
E846: Key code not set: t_kD
```

`:echo $TERM` reveals the following:

```
ansi
```

`:set term?` gives:

```
  term=ansi
```

## What to do?

I've seen this happen in the past, but I never knew what caused it and if I just mashed escape or quit and started again it would fix itself. On my new computer... it's there to stay.

I imagine this is just some sort of new default or option that I've enabled by accident.

None of my plugins (sensible, syntastic, solarized, rust) seem to be loading anyway, but I doubt that they'd be at fault for this.

Comment: If you're on the terminal, type `cat`, enter (to run the `cat` command) and while entering characters for it, enter a `fn`+`delete`, what do you see? I'm guessing something starting with `^[[` and having a `~` in it somewhere? But knowing exactly what should help figure out your particular case...

Comment: @filbranden I see `~^[[3` (question edited above).

Comment: Inside Vim, what does `:set t_kD` return? Wat about `:echo $TERM`?

Comment: @filbranden I get some errors `E846: Key code not set: t_kD` and `E15: Invalid expression: $TERM`

Comment: Odd, I can't reproduce E15 even if the $TERM variable is empty... In your shell, is $TERM set?  How about `:set term?` inside Vim? (Your problem is *probably* related to the terminal setting!)

Comment: For instance, see if `:set term=xterm` seems to fix your issue?

Comment: Ah your problem with `:echo $TERM` is you included a question mark at the end  Remove that, type only `:echo $TERM` to check it. (Sorry if this wasn't clear in my first comment...)

Comment: @filbranden `:set term=xterm` is the winner!! (also updated my answer again with the proper output) It was set to asni.

Comment: Alright, I'll write an answer for you! But note that setting `term=xterm` in Vim is just a workaround... Right answer is export TERM properly in your Terminal and shell... Are you using the native Mac Terminal.app? Or iTerm or similar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104862/discussion-between-coolaj86-and-filbranden).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you were having was related to the terminal setting, which you can find in the `$TERM` environment variable or in the `:set term?` option in Vim.

You had that variable set to `ansi`, which is a terminal setting fairly poor in features, missing a lot of the colors and support for special keys such as arrow keys, delete, etc.

You should configure your terminal setting to use a more featureful terminal, such as `xterm` or ideally `xterm-256color`.

In chat, we established you most likely got this setting from a profile in Terminal.app for the Solarized color scheme. Since the profiles include settings for everything (not just the color scheme), this `ansi` terminal emulation setting came with it. Switch it to `xterm-256color` and start a new shell (to get `$TERM` set right) and you should be good to go!